# What species are treated at St. Mungo's?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures, muggles

Who can be admitted to St Mungo's Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries?
Does the hospital admit non-human creatures? Does the hospital even have healers who are qualified to treat house elves, veela or goblins?
Do they treat muggles? Can a wizard, for example, bring in his muggle spouse and get medical help from healers?

Comment: Pretty sure they wouldn't heal Muggles. If you could get your spouse healed specially by magic, I doubt it would be at the hospital but in a rather more discrete manner. Before the Statute of Secrecy I believe they helped Muggles quite a lot, but then it was pretty much banned.

Comment: As Valorum points out, St. Mungo's treats Magical Maladies and Injuries in Muggles as well as Witches and Wizards. I see no reason why they would refuse to treat the same maladies and injuries in House Elves, Goblins, or other magical creatures, although it's possible they would have less skill in treating them due to a lack of specialised knowledge..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Magically-caused injuries (in Muggles) are treated at St Mungo's. It seems to be very much unusual, at least according to Mr Weasley who's something of an expert in Muggles and would be expected to know such things.

> *‘Anyway,’ said Mr Weasley, in a raised voice, ‘this time Willy’s been
> caught selling biting doorknobs to Muggles and I don’t think he’ll be
> able to worm his way out of it because, according to this article, two
> Muggles have lost fingers and are now in St Mungo’s for emergency bone
> re-growth and memory modification. Just think of it, Muggles in St
> Mungo’s! I wonder which ward they’re in?’*
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix**</sup></sub>

and

> *‘We have the same concerns,’ Fudge interrupted. ‘The Brockdale bridge
> didn’t wear out. That wasn’t really a hurricane. Those murders were
> not the work of Muggles. And Herbert Chorley’s family would be safer
> without him. We are currently making arrangements to have him
> transferred to St Mungo’s Hospital for Magical Maladies and Injuries.
> The move should be effected tonight.’*
>
> <sub><sup>**Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix**</sup></sub>

As to whether the spouse of a witch/wizard would be allowed to be visit St Mungo's, the answer is almost certainly yes. The partner in a mixed marriage is certainly allowed to know about magic and visit Diagon Alley so you'd expect them to be allowed to be treated at St Mungo's, albeit with the caveat that mundane Muggle maladies (cancer, for example) are likely to be treatable by *ordinary* wizarding healers anyway, obviating the need for a visit to the specialists at St Mungo's.

> I decided that, broadly speaking, **wizards would have the power to
> correct or override 'mundane' nature,** but not 'magical' nature.
> Therefore, **a wizard could catch anything a Muggle might catch, but he
> could cure all of it;** he would also comfortably survive a scorpion
> sting that might kill a Muggle, whereas he might die if bitten by a
> Venomous Tentacula. Similarly, **bones broken in non-magical accidents
> such as falls or fist fights can be mended by magic, but the
> consequences of curses or backfiring magic could be serious, permanent
> or life-threatening.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Pottermore - Illness and Disability by J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/illness-and-disability)</sup></sub>

Comment: I think the OP was mainly asking about magically treating Muggle injury/disease?

Comment: @DVK-In-Exile - Which I've addressed at the bottom. A competent wizard can cure any Muggle malady. Taking a Muggle to St. Mungo's for mundane health issues like ingrown toenails and cancer is overkill.

Comment: If I remember correctly, your second quote is from "HP and the Half-blood Prince", when Fudge addresses the Muggle Prime minister.

Comment: It answers perfectly the muggle part of the question and i couldn't dig up anything about the magical creatures part, so i think yours is the best answer under the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

According to Pottermore, all sapient species may be treated at St. Mungo's, for magical injuries, even if the victim happens to be a muggle. However, it is also stated that **ALL** mundane maladies are curable by magical means, so the hospital is holding back on its true healing abilities to the muggles, but this is to be expected under the Statute of Secrecy. Furthermore, just because a sapient species (wizard for example) recieved an injury which was mundane in appearance, does not mean that Mungo's wouldn't treat it, as Pottermore states that a leg broken using magic requires magical treatment, and will not heal properly through mundane methods, even though it is only a broken bone. My point, is that St. Mungo's will treat more than just humans, however humans are the main clientele, since they are injured by magic most frequently, and they have a greater access to the St. Mungo's facility.

Comment: "*According to Pottermore*". Which part of Pottermore is that from?

Comment: I am referring to the St. Mungo's tab under original writing by J.K. Rowling. Some of the information can also be found on the Harry Potter Wiki.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the article on Pottermore? I can't find it.